# Issue echoing variables in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I was working on a script to echo the date upon login in a different format but once I get down to echoing the result, it gives me a jumbled up output.  I've been searching online to see if I'm calling the variables wrong or using wrong ticks somewhere but no luck.  I even have echoed each individual variable before and after the problem echo and they echo the proper date/month/day of week.  **As my script is right now, it only puts out ". which is a Thu" when run.**  Also, I've been executing it with "sh ./datescript.sh" Any help/additional resources would be appreciated.  Thanks!

My Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
date=`date`     #NOTE: date being used in two different ways
day=`echo ${date} | cut -f1 -d' '`
month=`echo ${date} | cut -f2 -d' '`
date=`echo ${date} | cut -f3 -d' '`
echo "Today is the ${date}th day of ${month}, which is a ${day}."
echo $day
echo $month
echo $date
```

Comment: Your script works correctly on my systems.

Comment: Alright... I'm going to try it through vi instead and see if it works.  I was writing it in Notepad++ and copying over via ftp.

Comment: @Xattle - you may want to run `dos2unix` on it before attempting to run it

Comment: @Xattle that is indeed your problem. Notepad++ by default will use Windows new line characters `CRLF`, and bash won't interpret those properly as it's looking for UNIX new line characters `LF` only. In notepad++ you can click Edit --> EOL Conversion --> UNIX/OSX Format.

Comment: Why not just `date +"Today is the %-dth day of %B, which is a %A."`? This is unnecessarily complicated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can replicate the behaviour if I add `$'\r'` at the end of month and date assignment lines. Seems like Win/*nix line ending issue.

Run `dos2unix` or `fromdos` on the script to fix it.

Comment: It was a Win/*nix issue.  Once I tried it through vi, it worked fine.  Switching to UTF-8 encoding also ended up working.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

day=`date +%A`
month=`date +%B`
date=`date +%-d`

echo "Today is the ${date}th day of ${month}, which is a ${day}."
echo $day
echo $month
echo $date
```